# How to create a Counter object or a defaultdict in PoweShell

Tags: powershell, counter, defaultdict

I am writing a PowerShell script that examines a collection of objects and counts how many times various properties are seen.  In Python, I would use a Counter object, but PowerShell doesn't seem to have a standard counter/bag/multiset object. My need is fairly simple, so I could use a defaultdict, but that also doesn't seem to exist.  Is there a standard way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: See the conceptual [about_Hash_Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) help topic.

Comment: Create a new hashtable with `$ht = @{}`. To increment a counter by name just do `$ht['YourPropertyName']++`. PowerShell automatically inserts an initial integer value of zero, when the counter doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Depending on the kind of data you may also use the [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.3#examples) command to count the occurences of multiple things. The command is very versatile by the use of [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3).

Comment: @mklement0 I read the page you linked to and then searched for relevant terms in case I missed something, but don't see anything about [Autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification).

Comment: @zett42's comment shows an instance of it. if that doesn't help, you'll need to describe your requirements in more detail.